# Why is Rake Called Rake?

Tags: title, rake

I have been watching the American TV show [Rake](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2515462/), but I have seen no reference as to why the show is called "Rake". The main character is not named anything that even resembles a rake, and he does not work for a landscaping company.

Does anyone know why the show is called "Rake"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a reference to Keegan Deane's *character*.

In British English, the word 'rake' is used to describe someone who leads an immoral lifestyle.

From [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/rake_2), [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/rake) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_%28character%29):

> a man, especially one who is rich or with a high social position, who
>   lives in an immoral way, especially having sex with a lot of women
>
> ---
>
> OLD-FASHIONED a man who behaves in an immoral way, for example by
>   having sexual relationships with a lot of women
>
> ---
>
> A rake, short for rakehell (analogous to "hellraiser"), is a historic
>   term applied to a man who is habituated to immoral conduct,
>   particularly womanising. Often a rake was also prodigal who wasted his
>   (usually inherited) fortune on gambling, wine, women and song,
>   incurring lavish debts in the process. Comparable terms are
>   "libertine" and "debauchee".

The show is a remake of a popular [Australian series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_%28Australian_TV_series%29) and the title makes perfect sense to viewers over there. Because 'rake' and 'rakish' are words they would commonly use to describe someone like the protagonist.

Actually, the series synopsis contains a hint as to why the title exists. To quote from the [U.S. version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_%28U.S._TV_series%29):

> The series follows Keegan Deane, a criminal defense lawyer whose
>   personal problems and *self-destructive behavior* has him battling
>   wits and/or owing money to everyone around him, including his ex-wife,
>   judges, an assistant district attorney, his bookie, a brothel owner,
>   and the IRS.

Go over to [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2515462/board/nest/226255489?p=1) page for a colourful discussion on the same subject.

Comment: Thanks. I just got lucky. Considering I read it an hour after it was posted :-)

Comment: No, you did well my friend, well researched and presented, kudos.

Comment: Very thorough, thank you.  I knew it was a remake, and had wondered if it significance to the Australian audience, but hard to say what Hollywood does these days.

Comment: Glad to help! You're quite right. They're always 'repackaging' shows for US audiences. And yet, out of nowhere, something like this slips through the cracks :-)